# mySQL– list how many films had been directed?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, count

I just have got an exercise from school, where I have to display how many films the person in the task directed each year. How can I do that with mySQL? (I have already tried to pair the same year together)

```
SELECT * FROM Spielberg.spielbergData;

SELECT DISTINCT Year
FROM spielbergData
GROUP BY Year;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select year, count(*) no_films_directed
from spielbergData
where director = 'Yes'
group by year
order by year
```

Or if you want to display years when they directed no movie too, with a count of `0`:

```
select year, sum(director = 'Yes') no_films_directed
from spielbergData
group by data
order by year
```